# Accessing Other Page Controls From This Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Page 1  - `Ticket.aspx`, `DropDownList1`, `ModalPopUpextender` with id `mpe`

Page 2 - `Customer.aspx`, `btnSave`

The index change event of dropdown will pop up `mpe` which has an `iframe`. This `iframe` loads `Customer.aspx`.

I am trying to access `page1` controls in the button click event, but unable to.

**Customer.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void btnSave_Click()
{
  Ticket page = new Ticket();
  ModalPopUpExtender mpe = (ModalPopUpExtender)page.FindControl("mpe");
  DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)page.FindControl("DropDownList1");

  //error here - Object reference not set to an instance

    mpe.hide();

    ddl.selectedindex=0;
}
```

Why is this not working. Using a Session variable should work right?

Comment: maybe it's better to open Customer.aspx page with needed parameters in iframe? Like `Customer.aspx?someId=123`. Than on that page you can get it from Request.Query, and use it in your logic

Comment: You cannot access different pages from serverside without using `Server.Transfer` to show page2 and there via the `PreviousPage` property.  You might be able to access it on clientside via javascript. Pages are disposed on the server as soon as they were rendered.

Comment: @Sergey. I need to access the Modal and the DropDown. How should I do that please, with string params. Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Server.Transefer instead of Response.Redirect and then you can find the control in the current page.
Like:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("textbox1");
```

EDIT:

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    DropDownList ddl1 = 
        (DropDownList)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    if (ddl1 != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = ddl1.SelectedItem.Text; //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not transfering the page. Should show the 2nd one in a popup.

Comment: If you want the data of dropdownlist inside the iframe then you can also use ViewState.

Comment: Page1 has a ddl. its indexchange will pop up a model. This modal has an iframe whose src is page2.aspx. Page2 has a button. In this button click event, I should access the modal and drop down.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying may not be doable from the server side, but it can be easily be done with a little javascript. Here is a [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1058982.aspx) where you can get a working piece of code.

Hope this helps.